# how to add a text input area after selecting a additional information when select work type group?

Tags: lightning-scheduler

I have set up additional information pick list in work type group.
[image]

How can i add text input area blow for "Disability access required", just like "Other" below.
The "Other" is added by system by default, is there a way to get rid of it or can i change the label of Other?
Thanks for your help